# Only one Paint event is being called

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

My problem is that I have 8 pictureboxes and only one of them is getting their draw method called at a time.

My code is a bit too large so I tried to narrow it down to the affected portions as much as I could.

My best guess is that it's not so much a bug in my code, but a misunderstanding in how the draw event works.

I have a class which inherits from PictureBox which I am using instead of Picturebox.  The only change is the constructor

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DrawingSurface : PictureBox
{
    public DrawingSurface(Rectangle bounds) : base() {
        base.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        base.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        //I set the size and bounds which is probably redundant because 
        //I was trying random things to fix the problem
        base.Size = new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        base.Bounds = bounds;
        base.Margin = new Padding(0) ;
        base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}


public class MyForm:Form
{
    public MyForm():base()
    {
        base.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        base.MaximizeBox = false;
        base.MinimizeBox = false;
        base.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }

}
```

Here's my main class

```
class Program
{
    static int Main()
    {
        short boardOffsetX, boardOffsetY, trayOffsetX, trayOffsetY;
        MyForm gameImage = null;
        Tray playerTray = null;
        ScrabbleBoard board = null;
        BagOfLetters bag = null;


        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);//this line of code doesn't work either if any of you can spot anything obvious here.  

        //this is my hacky way of centering the images, wouldn't mind you telling me
        //a better way of doing this either.  
        boardOffsetX = (short)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width/4);
        boardOffsetY = (short)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/8);
        trayOffsetX = (short)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 3.3);
        trayOffsetY = (short)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 24);
        try
        {
            gameImage = new MyForm();
            bag = new BagOfLetters();
            board = new ScrabbleBoard(gameImage, new Point(boardOffsetX, boardOffsetY));
            playerTray = new Tray(bag, trayOffsetX, trayOffsetY, gameImage);
            gameImage.ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
             //Dispose all
        }
    }
}
```

My images are drawn like this.  I have one large class with a large image holds the 7 smaller classes and their images.  I try to initialize everything from my big class.

```
public class Tray{
    private Image TrayImage;
    private DrawingSurface TraySurface;
    private short OffsetY = 0;
    private short OffsetX = 0;
    public List<LB> Tray;

    public Tray(Bag bag, short offsetX, short offsetY, MyForm gameImage)
    {
        Letter tmp;

        //paramater validation

        TrayImage = Image.FromFile(PATHOFTRAY);
        //GetBoundsAsRectangle is just getting the image dimensions as a rectangle
        TraySurface = new DrawingSurface(GetBoundsAsRectangle()) ;
        TraySurface.Location = new Point(offsetX, offsetY);

        this.OffsetX = offsetX;
        this.OffsetY = offsetY;

        do
        {
            tmp = bag.PullLetter();
        }
        while (AddLetter(tmp, gameImage));
        //make this image draw
        TraySurface.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Draw);
        gameImage.Controls.Add(TraySurface);
        TraySurface.SendToBack();
    }


    public bool AddLetter(Letter letter, MyForm gameImage) {
        //argument validation
        Count++;
        letter.PutOnTray(Count, OffsetX, OffsetY);
        gameImage.Controls.Add(letter.GetDrawingSurface());
        if (letterCount >= MAXLETTERS)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs drawEvent)
    {
        //paramater validation here
        Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(OffsetX,
                                                            OffsetY,
                                                            TrayImage.Width,
                                                            TrayImage.Height);
        // Draw image to screen.
        drawEvent.Graphics.DrawImage(TrayImage, rectangleAreaToDrawImage);
    }
}

public class Letter
{
    private Image LetterImage;
    private DrawingSurface LetterSurface;
    private int PositionOnTray;

    public Letter(char value, String fName) {
        LetterImage = Image.FromFile(fName);
        LetterSurface = new DrawingSurface(GetBoundsAsRectangle());
    }


    public void PutOnTray(short position, short x, short y)
    {
        //validation
        PositionOnTray = position;
        TrayOffsetX = (short)(x + (position*20));
        TrayOffsetY = y;
        IsOnTray = true;
        LetterSurface.Location = new Point(TrayOffsetX, TrayOffsetY);
        LetterSurface.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Draw);
    }
    public void Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs drawEvent)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        //paramater validation here
        x = (TrayOffsetX + (LetterImage.Width * PositionOnTray));
        y = (TrayOffsetY + 6);
        Location = new Rectangle(x,
                                 y,
                                 LetterImage.Width,
                                 LetterImage.Image.Height);
        drawEvent.Graphics.DrawImage(LetterImage, Location);
}
```

So basically the tray has an image and the 7 letters also have images.  The letters get drawn on top of the tray for now, but in their own pictureboxes.  I added a draw method to tray and letter and added those to the pictureboxes Paint thingy. I need the letters to have seperate pictureboxes because later on I wanna add the functionality to have them be picked up and dragged around the screen with a mouse click.

The problem is that the paint methods aren't being called. Just theory wise with psuedocode, how would you go about painting this?  I am from a Java/C/C++ background and graphics were never my point of focus, so I am sure that rather than a bug, its how I am going about this that's wrong.

Comment: I assume this is winforms? Please add the appropriate platform tag! A note on `PictureBoxes`: They have a background, like all controls and you can draw on it in its Paint event. But their main feature is their Image, which you can set and modify; it takes care of keeping the Image always uptodate by itself. So where do you draw on? The Image or the background (which will be more or less covered if you have an image set)?

Comment: Murky.  The letters are added to the Form.  Very unclear how they relate to TraySurface, you'd expect the letters to be added to the TraySurface instead.  Using Color.Transparent is never not a problem either, transparency is simulated and stacking effects do not work.

Comment: I have updated my post.  It's System.Windows.Forms, so I assume winforms.

Comment: I have updated my post.  It's System.Windows.Forms, so I assume winforms.  I'm gonna try drawing in the pictureboxes paint event instead see if that works.  I drew with the image until now.  Commenting out the color transparent didn't change anything.  I honestly get the feeling that its just something stupid that I'm supposed to be doing that I'm not.  I basically cobbled this image code together from scraps I found online, so don't think too highly of it.

Comment: I don't have any specific advice, but I'm not sure I understand your need to have specific paint handlers - that's typically only used if you're implementing your own custom drawing, eg, perhaps you want a control that draws a background gradient or want to create a control that doesn't exist (a line separator control is a common one in C#).  To that end, I would expect that you'd be able to use vanilla picture boxes, and set them to the image you want, and move them around as needed. I might start with some simplification (work on building your parts first) and rebuild from there.

Comment: My images don't need their own paint handlers if I can get the images to draw in the specific positions I tell them to be drawn in.  The only thing I care about is that the images can somehow have mouse handlers later on and draw at position x/y width/height which I specify somehow.  If you have another way of doing that, then that's probably the answer right there.

Comment: I think I have an answer but I don't know if I will get all the functionality I need out of it.  What I am doing now is dropping all the pictureboxes and adding the draw event directly to the form.  That gets things to draw how I want, but will I still be able to add mouse functionality later with this?  Like I want to be able to pick up the images and move them around?

Comment: Do you know that you can move controls programmatically? PictureBox.Left and PictureBox.Top.

Comment: You may perhaps need to set the style to owner draw, that will guarantee you to call draw method everytime. Also use double buffered to avoid any flicker  while drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove all the pictureboxes...  All those events could be added directly to the form without issue.  I was originally thinking that I needed separate handlers provided through the pictureboxes for everything, but I was wrong.  It seems the event portion of Pictureboxes is pretty much unused except in rare instances like when you add them to a tablelayoutpanel.